# How can i test the state in react functional components?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am using jest and enzyme to test my components. If i have the following class component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class Test extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: false,
  };

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click button</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

then to write test for this i will use:

```
import {Test} from "../Test";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";

it('default state value for isLoading should be false', () => {
    const wrapped = shallow(<Test/>);
    const initialIsLoading = wrapped.state('isLoading');
    expect(initialIsLoading).toBe(false);
})

it('change isLoading true on button click', () => {
    const wrapped = shallow(<Test/>);
    const initialIsLoading = wrapped.state('isLoading');
    console.log(initialIsLoading);  
    wrapped.find('button').simulate('click');
    wrapped.update();
    const newValue = wrapped.state('isLoading');
    console.log(newValue);
    expect(newValue).toEqual(true);
})
```

but if my component is functional then i get error - `state cannot be used on functional components`

when i run my tests.

How can i test my functional components state ?

Answer (score 0):

`shallow` wrapper doesn't support hooks, which provide state to functional components. You can either use Enzyme's `mount` wrapper or switch to [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) which is better than Enzyme for modern generation of React.

Please note that `mount` can render stateful functional components, but not able to access the state. These will fail:

```
mount(<Test/>).setState();
mount(<Test/>).state();
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/#react-hooks-support) states that enzyme supports hooks with some limitations.

Comment: @Dima when i try - const wrapped = mount(<Test/>); i still get the same error. So with mount also functional hooks are not supported

Comment: @sdsd you are right. `mount` can render functional components, but you are not able to access the state in your tests.